# How to show progress in powershell script (determine OS version of computers from input list)

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I'm looking for assistance with a `powershell` script. I have created simple script to check `OS version` from the input list of servers.

It uses `Get-WmiObject`, and it takes a while to complete especially if there is more servers in input file.

I would like to show `progress bar` while the script is running.

I have looked at dozens of examples for Write-Progress, but all I was able to achieve is to display progress only for each of the server, but not for the script as a whole.

Script I have so far:

```
$ips = (Get-Content C:\ps\servers.txt)
ForEach ($ip in $ips) {
    $server = Get-WmiObject -comp $ip Win32_OperatingSystem
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Hostname = $server.__Server
        OS = $server.caption
        Version = $server.Version
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "...for the script as a whole"?

Comment: Well, I was able to display progress only for one server at the time. If I have 50 servers in input file, it shows progress bar from 0% to 100% 50 times. I just want only one progress bar until the script completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```psh
$ips = Get-Content 'C:\ps\servers.txt'

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ips.Count; $i++) {
  Write-Progress -Activity 'Getting OS information ...' -status 'Scanning server' `
    -PercentComplete ($i*100/ $ips.Count) `
    -CurrentOperation $ips[$i]

  $server = Get-WmiObject -Computer $ips[$i] -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    'Hostname' = $server.__Server
    'OS'       = $server.caption
    'Version'  = $server.Version
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to run it, but I get error message:
Write-Progress : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CurrentActivity'.
At line:6 char:21
+     -CurrentActivity <<<<  $ips[$i]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Progress], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteProgressCommand

Comment: @Martin_K My mistake. The parameter is named `-CurrentOperation`, not `-CurrentActivity`. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works now! I just added status to your code.